# How to access Kucoin OHLC data from API?

Tags: json, api, bitcoin, cryptoapi, cryptocurrency

I need to access kucoin Open-high-low-close data from Kucoin API.

Looking in https://docs.kucoin.com/#get-trade-histories, I deduced that to access OHLC data (for instance BTC versus USDT, with hourly timestamp), the address should be something like this :

```
https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/candles?symbol=BTC-USDT&type=1hour
```

Doing that, I get empty list for the data `{'code': '200000', 'data': []}`
(according to kucoin API doc, code `200000` correspond to a good request)

What I am doing wrong ?

ps : same method worked very well on kraken api (e.g. https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=xbtusd )

Thank you very much in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kukoin docs also mention two more arguments: startAt and endAt that are start and end of time interval in unix time format.

I tried

```
curl "https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/candles?symbol=BTC-USDT&type=1hour&startAt=1562460061&endAt=1562467061"
```

(7000 seconds interval).

and got the result

```
{"code":"200000","data":[["1562464800","11233.3","11186.4","11236.1","11185.2","145.83911572","1635403.570428367"],["1562461200","11196.7","11227.2","11236.5","11163.9","179.29402628","2009821.31982076"]]}
```